# Stålmarck's method, can triplets be dropped once they triggered equivalences

Tags: decision-problem, propositional-logic

In *Sheeran, Mary, and Gunnar Stålmarck*: **A tutorial on Stålmarck’s proof procedure for propositional logic** there is an example application of the method to`(((p -> p) -> p) -> (p -> q)) -> (((p -> q) -> p) -> q)` in which the authors mention that a triplets is "dropped" once it triggered a change in the equivalence relation, i.e., a simple rule applied for the triplet.

I am not sure that this is generally possible. Can a triplet trigger multiple changes or can it always be dropped once it triggers such a change?